# Equations in local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite commutative local ring with identity. Assume that every ideal in $R$ is principal.

Let $u$ and $v$ be units in $R$ and let $z\neq 0$ be a  zero divisor. I think that $uz=vz$ implies $u=v$, but I have troubles in finding a proof.

In fact if the maximal ideal of $R$ is generated by $\alpha$ then we can assume that $z=w\alpha ^t $, for a unit $w$.

Comment: This has nothing to see with local rings. If $z$ is a non-zero divisor, $\, uz=vz\Rightarrow (u-v)z=0\Rightarrow u-v=0$.

Comment: I think I explained  badly. In fact I mean that $z$ is a zero divisor but $z\neq 0$

Comment: Let $z = 4, u = 4$ and $v = 8$ in $\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$. Then $uz = 0 = vz$ would be a counter-example?

Comment: I think that both $4$ and $8$ are not units in $\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z$. So, the counter-example of Krijn do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is wrong: $R=\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$, $u=4$, $v=1$, and $z=3$.